# Upstart job: Pass command with escaped quotes to the exec stanza

Tags: command-line, upstart

I have an upstart job named `server.conf` to start a game server that contains the following

```
#!upstart

exec /srv/l4d2/srcds_run -game left4dead2 -tickrate 30 -maxplayers 8 -ip 192.168.1.1 "+map \"c1m1_hotel versus\"" +exec server.cfg
```

When I run  `start server.conf`, the job doesn't start and the log file says **/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string**

When run directly in the console, the command works just fine. So how to use it in the exec stanza without breaking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in the program that issued the error message: `/bin/sh`. The `sh` shell's quoting rules don't recognize "`\"`". See `man sh`. Use single quote "`'`" instead.

```
exec /srv/l4d2/srcds_run -game left4dead2 -tickrate 30 -maxplayers 8 -ip 192.168.1.1 "+map 'c1m1_hotel versus'" +exec server.cfg
```